# dask.read_csv much slower than pandas.read_csv with 50k columns

Tags: pandas, dask, read-csv

I have a csv with 1k rows and 50k columns.

I takes 9s to calculate the min of all columns with pandas

```
panda_df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",")           # 8s
mins = panda_df.min(numeric_only=True).values() # < 1s
```

But 86s with dask (it takes the same time if I reduce the file to 10 rows)

```
dask_df = dd.read_csv(path, sep=",", sample=512_000) # 14s
mins = dd.compute(dask_df.min(numeric_only=True))    # 72s
```

Any idea of how to tune dask to be as fast as pandas?
The Dask dataframe uses only 1 partition, so there shouldn't be overhead in partitioning.

Comment: First question is, do you really need Dask? Appart from that, without some data to reproduce it is hard to tell. dd.read_csv just read a little sample of the file, so it shouldn't take more time than pandas takes to load all the data.

Comment: As your dataframe fits in your memory, maybe is better to stay on pandas. I believe that dask has a bigger overhead, so a simple code like that becomes unproductive on dask b